# Why J2EE request.getParameNames() can not fetch parameter name of `<input type=file >`

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, request

html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="uimage" />
    <input type="text" name="uname" />
    <input type="text" name="uid" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

java:

```
for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    System.out.println("paramName:" + e.nextElement());
}
```

output:

```
paramName:uid
paramName:uname
```

I don't know why the output didn't contain `paramName:uimage`.
It really confuses me why it can't fetch the parameter name of `<input type='file'>` in java

I use SpringMVC

Comment: it's a multipart object so it will not come in `getParamaterNames();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(String str : ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getMultiFileMap().keySet()) {
    System.out.println("name:" + str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As user3145373 ツ said, it's not in the request parameters.  Submitted files can be large, so they get placed in the request body instead.

You probably want the [getPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
Path uimageFile = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
request.getPart("uimage").write(uimageFile.toString());
```